# How to get date set in method of calender type in jsp using jstl?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, gregorian-calendar

i am using a executing a query

```
select lastlevel as VERSION,name as DESCRIPTION,
TO_DATE(lastdate, 'DDMONYYYY_HH24:MI:SS') as RELEASEDATE
from mytable where rownum<=10
```

here the column lastdate is of varchar type

which give result like this

```
Version     Release Date        
1.0         2002-11-22

2.0     2003-02-08
```

i am setting the result of the above query like this
here setLastDate is of calender type,so i am setting the result of release date in the method like

```
if (rs.getString("VERSION") != null ) {             bean.setLastLevel(rs.getString("VERSION").trim());
}

if (rs.getDate("RELEASEDATE") != null ) 
{
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(rs.getDate("RELEASEDATE"));
bean.setLastDate(calendar);
}
```

the value is being set in the bean like this 2003-02-08.
at the end i am adding this result bean to an array list "list" like 
list.add(bean);

now i want all this value in jsp. I am using spring mvc so i return view with the arraylist "list".
when i am iterating the value in jsp
like this

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${list}">
<td valign="top">${list.lastLevel}</td>
<td valign="top">${list.lastDate}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

in jsp instead of getting date i am getting like this

```
Version     Release Date        
1.0          java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1037775600000,areFieldsSet=true,
```

areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="US/Arizona",offset=-25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=12,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2002,MONTH=10,WEEK_OF_YEAR=47,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=20,DAY_OF_YEAR=324,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-25200000,DST_OFFSET=0]

```
2.0          java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1044687600000,areFieldsSet=true,
areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="US/Arizona",offset=-25200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=12,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2003,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=6,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=8,DAY_OF_YEAR=39,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-25200000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

please help me in solving this.I need to get the date as in result.How to resolve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<td valign="top">${list.lastDate.time}</td>
```

It will call `getTime()` method on calendar instance which returns the `Date` instance

It is preferable not to use same var name as the attribute, call it `row` (or someother sensible variable name) instead and then `${row.lastDate.time}`

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${list}">
</c:forEach>
```

if you want the custom format output then

add

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

and use it like

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"  value="${list.lastDate.time}" />
```

Comment: thanks.. if i am using like above your suggestion i am getting date like this Wed Nov 20 00:00:00 MST 2002. i need date like 2003-02-08
 or Feb 8th 2003 in jsp using jstl

Comment: Thanks. i am not getting any value in jsp. I tried like this <fmt:formatDate var="releaseDate" pattern="MMM dd'th yyyy" value="${list.lastDate.time}"/>
<c:out value="${releaseDate} " />

Comment: Did you use `<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"  value="${list.lastDate.time}" />` ?

Comment: well just use `<fmt:formatDate pattern="MMM dd'th' yyyy" value="${list.lastDate.time}" />`