# Format datetime string in jsp?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

How can I format string1 to string2 in jsp? Please help me resolve this issue

```
String string1 = "2013-10-22 10:00:00',4";
String string2 = "10.00,4";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061409/how-to-get-date-set-in-method-of-calender-type-in-jsp-using-jstl

Comment: @JigarJoshi 1: This question is what was found by google easier. 2: That other question is very, very low quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the taglib directive to your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

You should be able to format the first string to the second string as follows. First convert string1 to an intermediate date:

```
<c:set var="string1" value="2013-10-22 10:00:00',4" />
<fmt:parseDate value="${string1}" var="theDate" 
     pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'',S" />
```

Then format it to the required format:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${thedate}" pattern="hh.mm,S" var="string2"/>
```

Which you can then use:

```
<c:out value="${string2}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSTL `<fmt:formatDate>` tag.